# Pysal does not have attribute open

Tags: pysal

Hi I am using Anaconda with Python 3.7 and I have imported Pysal to my environment. Now I am trying to import a dataset and open it with pysal, to my surprise it appears that pysal does not have attribute open...

```
import pysal as ps
import libpysal as lps

lps.examples.explain('us_income')
csv_path = lps.examples.get_path('usjoin.csv')
f = ps.open(csv_path)
```

I am getting an error `AttributeError: module 'pysal' has no attribute 'open'`

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The example dataset can be accessed using the modified script;

```
# Import packages
import pysal as ps
import libpysal as lps
# Load example data 
lps.examples.explain('us_income')
csv_path = lps.examples.get_path('usjoin.csv')

# Note the difference here 
f = ps.lib.io.open(csv_path)
```

These changes are a result of [PySAL migrating to 2.0](https://github.com/pysal/pysal/blob/master/MIGRATING.md). This assumes you are using PySAL >=2.0. Please mark this answer as correct if this answers your question.

Comment: module 'pysal' has no attribute 'lib'

Comment: Same result here:                                                                                                                         csv_path = lps.examples.get_path('usjoin.csv')
# Note the difference here 
f = ps.lib.io.open(csv_path)                                                                                                       Result: AttributeError: module 'pysal' has no attribute 'lib'

Comment: this was answered back in 2020, the API has changed since then :)